# AWS RDS Microsoft SQL Server 2019 "permission denied" for all actions

Tags: sql, sql-server, amazon-rds

I deployed a Microsoft SQL Server RDS instance in the AWS console.I thought everything was perfectly running (I restored a database with tables with I was able to edit and view) however after sometime I wanted to get manual backup of the SQL Server, right click on `Database->Tasks->Backup` but I get an error:

> The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'object_name' database 'mssqlsystemresource', schema 'sys'

Then everything I tried to grant permissions to the user ended up with "Permission Denied". Could you please guide me on how to get pass this error?

I have tried most of the solutions on the forum none of them worked. It says "Permission Denied" but I only have one master username and isn't that suppose to have the most privileges and also I am being restricted because I'm using AWS RDS ?

Comment: Are you using the admin account created via the username and password when the instance was created?

Comment: Yep I'm using admin password and username which is created on the AWS console @RossBush

Comment: Were you trying to use the backup and restore functions in SQL Server Management Studio against an AWS RDS database? Have you tried using the procs intended for use in RDS, `msdb.dbo.rds_backup_database` and `msdb.dbo.rds_restore_database`? Ref: [Importing and exporting SQL Server databases using native backup and restore](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/SQLServer.Procedural.Importing.html)

Comment: Yes I tried that and it returned successful but in the s3 there were no bak files uploaded and when I checked the job logs it gave an error saying that either there was some other backup in process or some other error without description was given

Comment: Can you post any related errors returned from exec msdb.dbo.rds_task_status?

Comment: Yesterday I was able to run this command without a problem but after the changes I have made when I run "USE [msdb] EXEC dbo.sp_help_job ; " query I get the error "Msg 229, Level 14, State 5, Procedure dbo.sp_help_job, Line 1 [Batch Start Line 0]
The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'sp_help_job', database 'msdb', schema 'dbo'. "

Comment: Are you using the master login when trying to execute `sp_help_job`? That system procedure requires the current login to hold one of the `SQLAgentUserRole`, `SQLAgentReaderRole` or `SQLAgentOperatorRole` roles in msdb. The master user gets the `SQLAgentUserRole` role applied when you create an RDS instance, but that's not a role that gets applied to any other login/user by default. Ref: [Using SQL Server Agent (AWS)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.SQLServer.CommonDBATasks.Agent.html).

Comment: Yes I'm using master login trying to execute "sp_help_job". When I run the query "EXEC msdb.dbo.rds_task_status;" I get the error " [2023-11-21 12:04:22.097] Aborted the task because of a task failure or an overlap with your preferred backup window for RDS automated backup. [2023-11-21 12:04:22.100] Task has been aborted [2023-11-21 12:04:22.103] Error making request with Error Code Forbidden and Http Status Code Forbidden. No further error information was returned by the service."